# \stepcounter is not working in subsection heading

Tags: counters

I have defined a new counter as:

```
\newcounter{lecCounter}
\newcommand{\lecID}{\stepcounter{lecCounter}\thelecCounter}
```

And I wish to use it as:

```
\subsection{Lecture \lecID }
```

But it gives error:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \csname\endcsname
l.1 \subsection{Lecture \lecID }

?
```

If I put `Lecture \lecID` outside of the `\subsection{}`, then it compiles.

What's the solution?

Comment: A quick tip: If you indent lines of code by four spaces -- easily accomplished by highlighting the lines in question and clicking on the `{}` "button" in the ribbon above the edit window -- the site software will pretty-print them automatically.

Answer (score 6):

The command `\stepcounter` is a fragile command, meaning it can lead to errors when put inside of a moving argument. Arguments to `\section` are moving arguments, since LaTeX will also puts the section name (the argument) in the table of contents and elsewhere. You need to "protect" `\stepcounter` to make sure it doesn't cause issues as a fragile command. We can either precede `\lecID` with `\protect` when it is used or just define `\lecID` as a robust command through `\DeclareRobustCommand`. (As Mico noted, we define `\lecId` with `\refstepcounter` in case you might need to refer to the `lecCounter` (`\lecCounter`) such that it will match up with the respective subsection.):

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\lecID}{\refstepcounter{lecCounter}\thelecCounter}
```

Furthermore, since `\lecID` is executed every time that it shows up, `lecCounter` is inappropriately incremented when it shows up elsewhere, such as with `\tableofcontents`. Thus, we use the optional argument of `\subsection` to put in only the counter without `\stepcounter` and `\refstepcounter` to change the value. LaTeX will therefore only increment `lecCounter` the first time it sees `\subsection`

```
\subsection[Lecture \thelecCounter]{Lecture \lecID }
```

The issue with fragile commands and moving arguments is explained more thoroughly here: [What is the difference between Fragile and Robust commands?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4736/what-is-the-difference-between-fragile-and-robust-commands).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\newcounter{lecCounter}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\lecID}{\refstepcounter{lecCounter}\thelecCounter}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\subsection[Lecture \thelecCounter]{Lecture \lecID}

\subsection[Lecture \thelecCounter]{Lecture \lecID}

\end{document}
```

[image: Showing result]

Comment: Just in case there are any plans to cross-reference the subsection by lecture number, it's preferable to use `\refstepcounter` instead of `\stepcounter`.

Comment: This will have peculiar effects if `\tableofcontents` is used.

Answer (score 6):

Don't use `\stepcounter` in the argument of `\subsection`. Even if preceding it with `\protect` in order to avoid the error, this will have adverse effect when `\tableofcontents` is used. The following example shows it clearly (I used `\section`, but it's exactly the same with `\subsection`, provided it goes in the table of contents).

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{lecCounter}
\newcommand{\lecID}{\protect\stepcounter{lecCounter}\thelecCounter}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Lecture \lecID}

Text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

What you should do is to define a new command:

```
\newcommand{\lecture}{%
  \stepcounter{lecCounter}%
  \subsection{Lecture \thelecCounter}%
}
```

Fine tuning is possible, depending on your needs; for instance if you need to refer to the lecture number rather than to the subsection number. Another possibility would be adding an optional argument for a specific lecture title. Better encoding all this into a command, rather than chasing into the document if a change is needed.

A sample document might be

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{lecCounter}
\newcommand{\lecture}{%
  \stepcounter{lecCounter}%
  \subsection{Lecture \thelecCounter}%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Group of lectures}

\lecture

Text.

\lecture

Text.

\end{document}
```