# How to use \ numberwithin if there is only section *

Tags: latex3

```
\documentclass[a8paper]{article} 

\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[mathletters]{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,ukrainian]{babel}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{indentfirst}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}
        \begin{center}
    \section*{\S 1. First}
       \end{center}
\begin{align}
            \overrightarrow{a} = a^1\overrightarrow{e_1}+a^2\overrightarrow{e_2}  \label{1.1}
        \end{align}
\begin{center}
    \section*{\S 2. Second}
       \end{center}
\begin{align}
            \overrightarrow{a} = a^1\overrightarrow{e_1}+a^2\overrightarrow{e_2}  \label{2.1}
        \end{align}
\end{document}
```

How to fix that instead of zero there was a section number

Comment: Do not link the section counter to the equations. Create your own counter. An example in this context you can find [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/219059/269505).

Comment: Are you sure the `a8paper` option is meaningful?

Comment: `\stepcounter{section}` should work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You load `titlesec`: use it!

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % no longer needed
\usepackage[english,ukrainian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{indentfirst}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\titleformat{\section}[block]
 {\filcenter\Large\bfseries}
 {\S\thesection.}
 {0.5em}
 {}

\begin{document}

\section{First}

\begin{equation}
  \overrightarrow{a} = a^1\overrightarrow{e_1}+a^2\overrightarrow{e_2}  \label{first}
\end{equation}

\section{Second}

\begin{equation}
  \overrightarrow{a} = a^1\overrightarrow{e_1}+a^2\overrightarrow{e_2}  \label{second}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Don't load `ucs`, it's obsolete and does nothing really useful.

Comment: and how then to pick up in tableofcontents figures

Comment: @AndrijMatviiv The table of contents will be automatically produced if you issue `\tableofcontents`.

Comment: yes but it will have 1 paragraph character and again 1

Comment: decided everything, thank you

Answer (score 3):

This is an XY problem. Your sections *are* numbered, so you should be using `\section` not `\section*` to begin with. To add the § you could use the capabilities of `titlesec` package, which you're already loading.

Not sure what you were attempting to do with the `center` environments, but if you want the section headings centered, you can do that as well.

```
\documentclass[a8paper]{article} 

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,ukrainian]{babel}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{indentfirst}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\titleformat{\section}[hang]%
    {\Large\bfseries\centering}% bold and Large and centered
    {\S\thesection.}% format of label
    {0.5em}% spacing between label and title
    {}% additional commands applied just to section title

\begin{document}
\section{First}

\begin{align}
    \overrightarrow{a} = a^1\overrightarrow{e_1}+a^2\overrightarrow{e_2}  \label{1.1}
\end{align}

\section{Second}

\begin{align}
    \overrightarrow{a} = a^1\overrightarrow{e_1}+a^2\overrightarrow{e_2}  \label{2.1}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image: titlesec results]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible solution:

```
\documentclass[a8paper]{article}

\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[mathletters]{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,ukrainian]{babel}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{indentfirst}

\newcounter{paragraphCounter}
\numberwithin{equation}{paragraphCounter}

\newcommand{\createParagraph}[1]{%
    \stepcounter{paragraphCounter}%
    \section*{\S\ \theparagraphCounter.\hfill#1}%
}

\begin{document}
    \createParagraph{First}
    \begin{align}
        \overrightarrow{a} = a^1\overrightarrow{e_1}+a^2\overrightarrow{e_2}
        \label{1.1}
    \end{align}

    \createParagraph{Two}
    \begin{align}
        \overrightarrow{a} = a^1\overrightarrow{e_1}+a^2\overrightarrow{e_2}
        \label{2.1}
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Remove the `\hfill` if you do not want the space between `X.` and `First`, `Two` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that does *not* employ the `titlesec` package. Instead, it employs a method I obtained years ago from the book The LaTeX Companion (2nd ed.).

[image]

```
\documentclass[a8paper]{article} % Are you sure 'a8paper' is meaningful?
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
%%\usepackage[mathletters]{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,ukrainian]{babel}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{old-arrows} % optional

%%\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\centering}
% Method proposed in "The LaTeX Companion", 2nd ed.:
\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{\@ifundefined{#1@cntformat}%
   {\csname the#1\endcsname\space}    %  default
   {\csname #1@cntformat\endcsname}}  %  enable individual control
\newcommand\section@cntformat{\S\thesection.\space}  % section level
\makeatother

\counterwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}

\section{First}

\begin{equation}\label{1.1}
\overrightarrow{a} = a^1\overrightarrow{e_1}+a^2\overrightarrow{e_2}  
\end{equation}
        

\section{Second}

\begin{equation}\label{2.1}
\overrightarrow{a} = a^1\overrightarrow{e_1}+a^2\overrightarrow{e_2}  
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```